# How can you utilize ul and li elements to permit multiple properly aligned columns where each column does not always have values

Tags: html, css

I have multiple ul sections within my HTML document.  Each one utilizes an unordered list of items.  For one very specific ul within the HTML, I have a list of items like so:

```
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>ck-item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
     <li>item 4</li>
     <li>ck-item 4</li>
     <li>item 5</li>
     <li>ck-item 5</li>
   </ul>
```

I am trying to find a way to use CSS and classes, so that for any ul that requires multiple columns, I can force the list above to result in the following:

```
item 1
item 2     ck-item2
item 3
item 4     ck-item4
item 5     ck-item5
```

Basically, regardless of how short or long the actual text of say "item 2" is, I want the second column of ck-item2 to line up horizontally with any other ck-item#s within the second column.  Essentially, a fixed amount of space between column 1 and 2, as if you were using a tab or something, so anything in column 2 lined up.

I have spent the past 8 hours trying to achieve this to no avail.  It seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but ...
Any assistance provided is appreciated.

EDIT: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  For example, I can do the following:

```
   <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2     ck-item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4     ck-item 4</li>
      <li>item 5     ck-item 5</li>
   </ul>
```

Unfortunately, with this approach, depending on how long the actual test is for "item 2, item 4, and item 5", you could end up with output that looks like:

```
item 1
item 2    ck-item 2
item 3
item 4   ck-item 4
item 5             ck-item 5
```

So it looks really ugly.  I hope that helps to explain what I am attempting to do.

Comment: There is no pure-CSS way to say "elements with `>` as their last character belong in a second column".   That's a bizarre way to structure your HTML; I'd suggest changing it to nested lists or a table.

Comment: Agreeing with @DanielBeck - it appears what is happening here is you are using a semantically mismatched element to attempt to display your data.  Even if you _could_ figure out a way to hack it with CSS, it would likely be confusing to read (in code), difficult to maintain, bad for SEO and bad for assistive technologies like screen readers.  I would recommend reviewing your data and reassessing the most semantically appropriate way to wrap it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

See the example below, with explanation following it:

```css
.ul-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.ul-table li {
  border: dashed 1px red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ul-table li.start-new-row {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-table">
  <li class="start-new-row">item 1</li>
  <li class="start-new-row">long item 2</li>
  <li>ck-item 2</li>
  <li class="start-new-row">very very long item 3</li>
  <li class="start-new-row">item 4</li>
  <li>ck-item 4</li>
  <li class="start-new-row">item 5</li>
  <li>ck-item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Explanation for the **.ul-table** style:

- `display: grid;` Enables grid layout.
- `grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;` Creates 2 columns, each just wide enough to contain the longest text present in that column.
- `column-gap: 20px` = Spacing between columns.

And for the **.start-new-row** style:

- `grid-column-start: 1;` Starts a new grid row.